# How do I display background images in Pygame for a set period of time, and then change the background image?

Tags: python, time, pygame, display

My goal is to have a series of backgrounds display over time, that I can then display sprites over to create a game boot animation, like the original Pokemon Red/Blue had (Video reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C19O5xm51dk)

Here is the code I have so far. I have 2 comments at the bottom as psuedo-code while I've been looking for solutions, but each time I try something new, the first image does not display, and it immediately displays the second image.

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame import mixer
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
mixer.init()

HEIGHT = 576
WIDTH = 640
FPS = 60
 
FramePerSec = pygame.time.Clock()
 
displaysurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Pykemon")

blank_img = pygame.image.load('../Pykemon/Intro and Title Images/blank.png')
blank_img = pygame.transform.scale(blank_img, (640, 576))
copyright_screen_img = pygame.image.load('../Pykemon/Intro and Title Images/copyright screen.png')
copyright_screen_img = pygame.transform.scale(copyright_screen_img, (640, 576))

def background_img(image_name):
    displaysurface.blit(image_name, dest)

dest = (0, 0)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    displaysurface.fill((255,255,255))

    background_img(copyright_screen_img)

    # Hold this image for 3 seconds

    displaysurface.fill((255, 255, 255))

    background_img(blank_img)

    # Hold this image for 3 seconds

    pygame.display.update()
    FramePerSec.tick(FPS)
```

I have tried to use pygame.time.get_ticks() to create an if statement that changes the image based on ms passed, but it runs into the same issue, displaying only the second image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control something over time in Pygame you have two options:

1. Use [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to measure time and and implement logic that controls the object depending on the time.
2. Use the timer event. Use [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) to repeatedly create a [`USEREVENT`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) in the event queue. Change object states when the event occurs.

Save the background image you want to draw in a variable. Change the variable after a certain amount of time has passed:

```py
background_image = copyright_screen_img

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if current_time > 3000 # 3000 milliseconds == 3 seconds
        background_image = blank_img

    displaysurface.fill((255,255,255))
    background_img(background_image)

    # [...]

    pygame.display.update()
    FramePerSec.tick(FPS)
```